# Css transition happens during load

Tags: html, css

I have a button with some styling but when i load the page, the transition on that button fires. So you see an ugly load from no padding to a button with padding.

This is how i load the css:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $metaDescription; ?>">
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $canonical; ?>" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/fontawesome5/all.min.css">
 <!-- Bootstrap CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

The button html:

```
<a href="contact" class="button primary">Contact us</a>
```

The button scss:

```
.button {
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;

&.primary {
    background-color: $black-color;
    color: $white-color;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    font-weight: 300;
    border-radius: $border-radius;
    transition-duration: $transition-duration;

    &::after {
        @include pseudoElement($content: "\f054", $top: 50%, $right: 16px, $height: auto, $width: auto, $font-family: $font-awesome);

        transform: translate(0, -42%);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    &:hover {
        padding: 20px 44px 20px 36px;

        &::after {
            right: 24px;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the ```button``` with its ```html``` and ```css```?